# Kotlin logic conversion to Java problem with method "contains"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to use the following piece of code posted on [goo.gl/av3tJD](http://goog.gl/av3tJD)

```
val supportsDistortionCorrection = characteristics.get(

    CameraCharacteristics.DISTORTION_CORRECTION_AVAILABLE_MODES)?.contains(

    CameraMetadata.DISTORTION_CORRECTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY) ?: false
```

I see the code is in Kotlin, which I know very little about. 
I want to convert the code to Java.

I'm trying the following:

```
Boolean hasNoiseReduction = false;
//cc is my previously defined CameraCharacteristics object
if(cc.get(CameraCharacteristics.DISTORTION_CORRECTION_AVAILABLE_MODES).contains("some string"))hasNoiseReduction = true;
```

The method ***contains*** is throwing me off. I don't believe is the method contains used in the String class.

Any advice is needed

Comment: It is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: oh wow, and I thought it was Kotlin. Any ideas how to convert it to pure Java? @forpas

Answer (score 2):

`it.first` at that point in the code is referring to the first element of the `Pair` created above, containing a `CameraCharacteristics` instance. The `get` on this returns an `IntArray` (`int[]` in Java terms), and the [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html) method from the Kotlin standard library checks whether the given constant is in that array.

```
val cameraCharacteristics: CameraCharacteristics = it.first
val capabilities: IntArray = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES)!!
capabilities.contains(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA)
```

You could check this in Java by - for example - looping through the array elements and seeing if you find the value. A primitive implementation for this:

```
CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = ...;
final int[] capabilities = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES);

boolean contains = false;
for (final int capability : capabilities) {
    if (capability == CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}

// use result
```

Comment: Hey thanks @zsmb13 and That is what I just did. Created the int[] array and looped through it. Someone above in the comments was saying it is some type of construct from javaSE from oracle. I take it is pure Kotlin code construct?

Comment: Yes, the `contains` call in this code is a function in the Kotlin standard library, defined as an extension on int arrays.